# UNION OF 2-3 TREES?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, b-tree

I have two 2-3 tree T1 (with n1 keys) and T2 (with n2 keys)

Knowing each key in T1 is less than every key in T2 how can I return a 2-3 tree which holds the union of the keys in `O(max{log(n1),log(n2)})`?

I'm looking for the idea/algorithm rather than the code which I could write in my own.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is handy to merge not just two trees, but through a key. So you would create a temporary key, which key would be greater than values in T1 and less than values in T2.

I would assume that the rank (height) of T1 is at least the rank (height) of T2.

Now let's do a recursion over T1 to find the correct height to insert T2 into it. We know that the tree we are merging with should be the right-most subtree, so on each recursion depth there are two cases: either the subtrees of this vertex have the same rank (height) as T2, or they are greater. If we met the first case, we add our temporary key as rightmost of this vertex, and to the right of it we add T2, else we go recursively and merge the rightmost tree with T2. Then, same as in addition, we keep invariants of 2-3 tree by splitting vertices that have four keys ascending the tree from addition point. At the very end we delete the temporary key from the tree, and therefore now have the result.

If the assumption about the ranks (heights) was the other way round, just do the same, but with recursion over T2 and going to leftmost trees.

Comment: "Now let's do a recursion over T1" Where is the recursion exactly hear, can you elaborate (I found something quit different but would like to understand this one too)

Comment: @MrCalc one of the invariants of 2-3 tree is that all subtrees for one vertex have the same height. Therefore, you should insert your tree at exactly the right height of the tree, and that can be done recursively. You can also find it with a loop, but then splitting vertices on the way back up the tree might be a bit of a pain.

Comment: But why you need to split things at all, that key is complicating things we can just find the place on where to connect them and fix the path..

Comment: @MrCalc you can't just connect things, because it would break the property of subtrees having identical height. You would need to merge trees of the same height anyway, you can do it either in the operation itself or through this trick with the temporary key, which I myself find easier to understand. When you would delete this temporary key you would merge this trees anyway. Sorry if you have found it confusing.

Comment: My point is suppose the h1 = 5 and h2=2 then I go 3 layers down and connect T2 to T1 then I simply fix the path

Comment: But where do you connect it? The vertex with 2 keys should have 3 subtrees, and the vertex with 3 keys should have 4. You can't just add the root to the list of keys, without merging one of its subtrees, and you can't just add it as a subtree, because there is never a place for an additional subtree in a vertex.

Comment: I connect them at that level as the right most son, what's the problem with this? like if it had 3 sons I add another one and then do the work (split and fix the path and so on)

Comment: If you mean adding it as a subtree, then you straight up can't because there would already be a tree there. If you mean copying root elements to the vertex, then the rightmost from T1 at this level and the leftmost from the T2 root, again, should be placed in the same place.

Comment: Yes I mean adding it as a subtree, why I can't? 2-3 trees can hold up to 3 so if it's 2 I can add one if it's 3 I change the tree to have one extra ptr (tmp)

Comment: Because in any B-tree each vertex always has exactly keys+1 subtrees. If it won't be like this, you won't be able to choose which tree suits your element when descending the tree in almost any operation. Thus, if you want to add it as a subtree, you also need to add a key, that would separate new subtree from original ones.

Comment: we are talking about 2-3 trees not B

Comment: 2-3 trees are B trees

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the heights of trees, find the heights H1 and H2. Finding them takes O(log(n1)) and O(log(n2)) time. You can start from the root, go to the first child of each node, and count the nodes you see until you get to a leaf.

**If their heights are equal:**

Create a new root, set its first child to T1 and second child to T2, and assume it has a key with a proper value. Now delete this dummy key. You should get the merged tree in O(log H) time, using a usual deletion algorithm for B-trees.

**If the height of T2 is lower than the height of T1:**

Start from the root of T1. Go to the rightmost child of current node, H1 - H2 - 1 times *(O(H1))*. Assume you appended a dummy key after the rightmost key in this node, set the child pointer after the dummy key to point to T2. If this breaks the B-tree properties (if this is the 3rd key), fix the properties, the way they are fixed in insertion algorithms *(O(H1))*. You may want to store the new location of the dummy key. Finally, delete the dummy key *(O(H1))*.

**If the height of T1 is lower than the height of T2:**

Same as previous part, but mirrored. (Start from T2, descend to left children, insert to the left side etc.)

You don't need to actually calculate a suitable dummy key in any of these cases. You can simply assume it has a proper value, and ignore its value during these operations.